# VS2013 with GitHub - Stop JS files made from typescript files from commits

Tags: visual-studio, github

I am using `Visual Studio 2013` and `GitHub` for my source control, and a problem I keep having is that it keeps trying to commit all of the `.js` files that are generated from `.ts` *(Typescript)* files.

The reason this is bad is because I've had experiences where committing these causes building to fail, and only closing and re-opening Visual Studio fixes the issues.

My knowledge of git is still rudimentary in general, but it seems to me this must be a common problem. I do not want to just exclude all `.js` files because there are many that are not generated from typescript; So is there anything I can do about this other than MANUALLY excluding the files every single time I do a commit?

Comment: Are the JavaScript files you wish to exclude contained in separate directories from the ones you wish to commit?

Comment: Yes. All of the typescript files in the entire project are underneath a single place, any non-typescript javascript files go somewhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add some file patterns to one of Git's *ignore files*.

- The `.gitignore` file is usually committed with the repository, so its ignores are shared by all users.
- The `.git/info/exclude` file is not committed with the repository, so it can be used for your own personal ignores.

To ignore all `.js` file in a directory `foo`, use something like this:

```
foo/*.js
```

*Note that patterns in the ignore files only prevent files from being tracked. This means that **if you have already committed a file, it will continue to be tracked**. Modifications will cause the file to show up in your "uncommitted changes", and something like `git commit -a` will cause changes to be committed.*

If you have a committed file that you wish to ignore going forward, you will have to remove it from the repository. This is a frequent question on SO, and there are many questions about handling this.

It is worthwhile to read up on Git's ignore feature, as it has a few gotchas.

- [The `gitignore` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
- [GitHub's "Ignoring files" help page](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)
- [A popular SO question about removing already tracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Comment: Hrnn. This doesn't seem to work. I used `*scripts/home/*.js`, and it is still trying to commit `js` files that are in that folder, or a folder inside of it.

Comment: This is my `.gitignore` file, http://pastie.org/pastes/9142933/text?key=dzvlemds4joimfo4ysalq - and the file it is trying to commit is `app_content/scripts/home/app/init.js`.

Comment: @Ciel, you've found one of the gotchas :-). Try using `scripts/home/**/*.js`. As explained in the manpage link above, "A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, `a/**/b` matches `a/b`, `a/x/b`, `a/x/y/b` and so on." You may need the leading `*/` that is in your current pattern, but I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to have fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Yay! This is so totally awesome! I have been able to make all kinds of cool flexations to this to make it work exactly how I want! Thank you so much again!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is this feature request : http://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/253

For now, I used

- rename file, ex, `myfile.ts.ts`
- include in *.gitignore* my auto-generated typescript `*.ts.js` and `*.ts.js.map`

Comment: Great idea. Beleza!